# MySQL - how should i go about doing JOIN for this ? (explain too thanks)

Tags: mysql

Kindly explain how to go about using JOIN to display the desired output as I only know how to display first two columns (and idk if its correctly used). Thanks in advance for helping this newbie out :D

`TRIED:`

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", client.client_firstname, client.client_lastname) AS A_name, relationship.rel_client1_state AS A_state
 FROM client
  INNER JOIN relationship on client.client_id = relationship.rel_client1_id;
```

`The database`

```
CREATE TABLE client ( 
client_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
client_firstname VARCHAR(30), 
client_lastname VARCHAR(30)  
); 

CREATE TABLE relationship ( 
rel_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
rel_client1_id INT(6), 
rel_client1_state VARCHAR(30), 
rel_client2_id INT(6), 
rel_client2_state VARCHAR (30) 
); 

INSERT INTO client (client_id, client_firstname, client_lastname) VALUES ('1', 'James', 'Potter');
INSERT INTO client (client_id, client_firstname, client_lastname) VALUES ('2', 'Harry', 'Potter');
INSERT INTO client (client_id, client_firstname, client_lastname) VALUES ('3', 'Lily', 'Potter');

INSERT INTO relationship (rel_id, rel_client1_id, rel_client1_state, rel_client2_id, rel_client2_state) VALUES ('1', '1', 'Father', '2', 'Son');
INSERT INTO relationship (rel_id, rel_client1_id, rel_client1_state, rel_client2_id, rel_client2_state) VALUES ('2', '3', 'Wife', '1', 'Father');
```

Expected:

A_name       | A_state  | B_name      | B_state

James Potter | Father   | Harry Potter | Son

James Potter | Husband  | Lily Potter  | Wife

Actual output:

A_name       | A_state

James Potter | Father

Lily Potter  | Wife

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to get client data for two clients (both sides of the relationship) you need to join the `relationship` table to the `clients` table twice, first based on the `rel_client1_id` and then on the `rel_client2_id`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', c1.client_firstname, c1.client_lastname) AS A_Name,
       r.rel_client1_state AS A_State,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', c2.client_firstname, c2.client_lastname) AS B_Name,
       r.rel_client2_state AS B_State
FROM relationship r
JOIN client c1 ON c1.client_id = r.rel_client1_id
JOIN client c2 ON c2.client_id = r.rel_client2_id
```

Output:

```
A_Name          B_Name          A_State B_State
Lily Potter     James Potter    Wife    Husband
James Potter    Harry Potter    Father  Son
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wV35N8gjTEiCzw3rK1STTU/0)

Comment: Oh I understand now, didnt know can join twice. Thanks Nick~!